# Php windows server queues new requests and doesn't respond immediately until the current one finishes

Tags: php, laravel

I have xampp server running locally on my windows 11 machine. I start my Laravel 10 application with the command php artisan serve. In my project, I have one page that gets the uploaded file and resize it with Spatie library. I caught up php by not responding new requests until resizing image completes which means php server queues new requests until the current one finishes.

How can I achive multitasking php server with responding requests simultaneously?

I have tried

```
session_start();
session_write_close();
```

without success.

I am using Php 8.2 and laravel 10

Comment: "_I have xampp server running_" Why are you using `php artisan serve` then, why not use Apache?

Comment: It is electron desktop app. I am using gulp-connect-php @brombeer

Answer (score 0):

This is because the session_start() function will create a lock on session. The session lock will be released only when the session_write_close() is called in the same request. If not called the session lock will be called by php runtime at the end of the php page execution.

So if you call the page with session_start() multiple times, second request  will get locked at session_start() function until the first request calls session_write_close() .

Fix is to make sure to close the session(ie call session_write_close()) immediately rather than waiting till the end of the page to close it or use session start only when you need to access session data and use session_write_close() asap once the session access is over.

Read the session_write_close() function manual for more details.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php